# Alternative approaches for Debugging a Visual Studio .net application using azure service bus

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azureservicebus, sharepoint-apps

In the past when I develop SharePoint Provider-Hosted apps which implement remote event receivers, i use the Azure Service Bus to debug the code, as mentioned in this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ , where inside Azure i create a new service bus >> i copy the primary connection string, as follow:-
[image]

then inside the Visual Studio project >> Properties >> SharePoint >> i add the above service bus's primary connection string, as follow:-
[image]

this was allowing me to debug my code. but last week when i tried to do so, I got these errors inside Visual studio after running the project:-

> One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure
> Service Bus. Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on
> Microsoft Azure Service Bus: Unable to connect to the remote server

as follow:-
[image]

so i read that using azure service bus has been retired by Microsoft starting from september 2018. but at the same time i did not find any alternative for using Azure Service Bus for debugging the sharepoint provider hosted app. So can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngrok as a proxy](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/) to debug your application locally without using Service Bus.

The issue with passing localhost to Sharepoint is that Sharepoint cannot talk to it as you have pointed out. ngrok provides you with a public URL that Sharepoint can reach that is then is routed to your local machine via the ngrok service.This is the same thing that Service Bus was doing- offering a public URL routed to your local.

Instead of registering localhost:44332/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc with Sharepoint, you would register {id}.ngrok.io/Services/AppEventReceiver where id is the id generated when you start the local ngrok service.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. using reverse proxy will not work if i am creating my remote event reciver using the steps mentioned here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ .. i will get an error "Sorry, something went wrong with adding the app"

Comment: and i will get this error on the app "The remote event receiver callout failed.
Details: There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44332/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

Comment: I incorrectly called ngrok a reverse proxy instead of a proxy service. I have also added more info on why this approach functions the similar to how the Service Debugging works.

Comment: i already tried the ngrok appraoch, but the sharepoint add-inn did not get deployed correctly where i got this error `Details: There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44332/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.`.. now maybe i am missing something,, is how i need to register `{id}.ngrok.io/Services/AppEventReceiver ` inside visual studio project? in my case i just kept the ngrok command window open...

Comment: The original example used Powershell to register the app with Sharepoint with the ngrok domain. Here's another example where someone is using Azure Functions as the receiver. They go through the process of setting up the urls in a lot more detail. https://spblog.net/post/2017/09/09/Using-SharePoint-Remote-Event-Receivers-with-Azure-Functions-and-TypeScript